# The water in my cactus oozed out when I moved the pots and now it is kind of deflated, is it dead, is there any way to help it?

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

The water in my cactus oozed out when I moved the pots and now it is kind of deflated.  Is it dead, is there any way to help it?
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from your picture, but you probably overwatered it for a long time, or the pot doesn't have any drain holes, and it rotted away from the inside. Eventually the rot reached the surface and it "leaked water" and "deflated". If that is what happened, then it's dead. It may have actually been dead for a long time (several months) but you didn't realize that.

Comment: If some part of the cactus is not rotten (you’ll have to cut it to check), then it’s possible to propagate it from this part.

Comment: Update: I tried to look at the roots like you said and the top broke off. I found a website that says that I should dry it about and let the bottom callus over, should I trust it?

Comment: Real cacti, like this one, like their water on the order of once every couple months, if you remember. They thrive on what other plants would call abuse. Treat them nice and they *will* die on you.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any rotten material on what's left, cut it off until you get to good material. Let it dry and see if you can root it.

But, yeah, leaking is a bad sign for a cactus.